# How to disable '-- INSERT --' text beneath statusline?

Tags: statusline, plugin-powerline

I have powerline statusline plugin and `set laststatus=2` in `.vimrc`, so I have two places it tells me my mode in. What is the bottom one called and can I disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [airline-FAQ](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/wiki/FAQ):

> How do i get rid of the default mode indicator?
>
> Add `set noshowmode` to your vimrc.